# Voice Sampling with Java

Tags: java, voice-recognition, sampling

I am trying to develop an application which will record voice and plot a graph accordingly.

Following is the output which I am expecting.

When User1 records a sound say "Hello" system should generate a graph say "Graph A". Now when User2 records same sound as "Hello" system should generate "Graph B" i.e (Graph A != Graph B). Now again User1 records same sound as "Hello" system should generate same graph "Graph A".

I am using java sampling algorithm for this, but sound recorded second time always vary than recorded previously (may be because of background noise, natural variations in voice or other factors).

My questions are 
1. Is it really doable?
2. Is there any built in library in JAVA to achieve the output.

Comment: It is normal to be different since we are not robots. What language do you target? Do you want to build a speech recognition system? There are some implementation done in Java, such as http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Seitaridis No, I am not trying for speech recognition. I just want to detect the user. What do you mean by Language? Programming language is Java. Spoken language is Sanskrit.

Comment: Seems like the problem you are tyring to solve is speaker verification/identification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_recognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing a little bit with simple sound compression/recognition libraries and I have come across 
this

http://code.google.com/p/musicg-sound-api/downloads/list

You can record sound to wav format and then compare two (or more) wav files getting similatity level (%)

Comment: Will it filter or handle disturbances like background noise, etc.?

Comment: @Ravinder, I think the disturbances will create small differentiation say 5-8%. We can possibly handle it in coding.

Comment: @Ravinder yes, as it is mentioned by Uday Sawant above it is totally dependent on the percentage of similarity that one want to achieve. As to my knowledge it would be difficult to cut off background noise unless it is in the same range (engine, crowd etc), if it varies how can one tell what is what (frequency narrowing?)